# ASP.net model validation isn't correct

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model:

```cs
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int In_stock { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int External_id { get; set; }
}
```

Create handler of post request

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct(Products product)
```

In controller validate model

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

It's true if I pass this json

```
{
    "name": "something",
    "description": "something"
}
```

but if name or description property doesn't exist in JSON it'll be an error.

I guess when product create all fields(beside string fields) initialize 0.

So how can I fix that?

Comment: If you want `int`, `decimal` or `DateTime` properties to fail validation if not set mark them as nullable `int?`, `decimal?` or `DateTime?`. Otherwise they will never be null and initialised to their default values.

Comment: what error message? that these fields are required?

Comment: I get no error when name and description properties exist in json but I need if any property(besides id) doesn't exist it shouldn't pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the validation works on the already-bound model object, not on the input data that was used to create that model. In your model you have non-nullable `int`, `decimal` and `DateTime` properties, so they will always have their default value (`0` or `MinDate`) if not specified in the request, therefore validation will pass (your model just doesn't allow for those properties to be null). So basically what phuzi said - change them to `int?`, `decimal?` and `DateTime?`.

If the `Products` class is a domain model (where you actually want those properties to be non-nullable), consider creating a separate model for binding and validating the request and then map it to your domain model.